# Получение файла из буфера обмена в Python

Tags: python, файлы

Приведу пример: Копируешь в папке файл, а мне надо с помощью Python по скрипту найти путь скопированного файла из буфера обмена. Допустим я скопировал файл C:\test.txt, и Python должен найти этот путь "C:\test.txt".

Извините что так странно пытаюсь довести суть, но надеюсь что вы поняли.

Comment: вопрос-то какой? И что значит "скопировал файл"? Есть как минимум две разные трактовки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы говорим конкретно о Windows, то такое можно реализовать через её апи. Установка `pywin32`:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Получение данных из буфера обмена:

```
import win32clipboard


def get_clipboard_data():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    try:
        return win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_HDROP)
    except TypeError:
        return None
    finally:
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()


print(get_clipboard_data())
```

Мой вывод после копирования двух ярлыков с рабочего стола:

> ('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Telegram.lnk',
> 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord.lnk')

Comment: Спасибо большое!